# How do you implement leaflet plugin "Leaflet-Pegman" in R Leaflet

Tags: javascript, r, leaflet, google-street-view, r-leaflet

I want to use google streetview in my r shiny application. I am using leaflet to draw my map. I found this great leaflet plugin "[Leaflet Pegman](https://github.com/Raruto/leaflet-pegman)".

How do I implement this plugin into a r shiny app?

I tried to use this [explanation](https://gist.github.com/jcheng5/c084a59717f18e947a17955007dc5f92).
I also found another R-package ([googleway](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleway/vignettes/googleway-vignette.html)) but in my case I want to use leaflet instead.

Could some one provide me a working example. This is my code now:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools)
library(htmlwidgets)

Googlekey <- "api_key_here"

PluginPegman <- htmlDependency(name = "Pegman",version = "0.1.4"
                               ,src = c(href = "https://unpkg.com/leaflet-pegman/0.1.4/")
                               ,script = "leaflet-pegman.js"
                               ,stylesheet = "leaflet-pegman.css")

registerPlugin <- function(map, plugin) {
  map$dependencies <- c(map$dependencies, list(plugin))
  map
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css","html,body {width:100%;height:100%}")
  ,leafletOutput("map",width = "100%",height = "100%")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      # Set view to the Netherlands
      setView(5.41077,52.13012,zoom = 8) %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap,group = "OSM") %>%
      
      registerPlugin(PluginPegman)  %>%
      onRender("function() {
      var pegmanControl = new L.Control.Pegman({
      position: 'bottomright', // position of control inside the map
      theme: 'leaflet-pegman-v3-default', // or 'leaflet-pegman-v3-small'});
      pegmanControl.addTo(map);
               }")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you very very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to include the leaflet-pegman js file in the `head` of the UI for it to work. I also edited the link in the `htmlDependency` as it wasn't referencing the correct link.

This code works for me now:

```r
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools)
library(htmlwidgets)

Googlekey <- "api_key_here"

PluginPegman <- htmlDependency(name = "Pegman", version = '0.1.5'
                               ,src = c(href = "https://unpkg.com/leaflet-pegman")
                               ,script = "leaflet-pegman.js"
                               ,stylesheet = "leaflet-pegman.css")

registerPlugin <- function(map, plugin) {
    map$dependencies <- c(map$dependencies, list(plugin))
    map
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
    tags$head(
        tags$script(src='https://unpkg.com/leaflet-pegman@0.1.5/leaflet-pegman.js'),
        tags$style(type = "text/css","html,body {width:100%;height:100%}")
    ),
    
    leafletOutput("map",width = "100%",height = "100%")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>%
            # Set view to the Netherlands
            setView(5.41077,52.13012,zoom = 8) %>%
            addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap,group = "OSM") %>%
            registerPlugin(PluginPegman)  %>%
            onRender("function(el,x) {
      var pegmanControl = new L.Control.Pegman({
      position: 'bottomright', 
      theme: 'leaflet-pegman-v3-default',
      apiKey: YOUR API KEY});
      pegmanControl.addTo(this);}")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```